# function of three variable is even than $f(a,b,c)=f(|a|,|b|,|c|)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

I used in the proof of [Hlawka's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HlawkasInequality.html) you can find the link here [Hlawka's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039955/forall-x-y-z-in-mathbbr-show-that-xyyzxz-leq-xyzxy)

that's if i have  function of three variable is even in each variable, so that :

$$f(a,b,c)=f(|a|,|b|,|c|)$$

but a teacher that I know told me why you generalize it for the three variable, I told him that we note $x,y$ and $z$ play symmetric roles in the inequality he said even that you don't have right to say  $$f(a,b,c)=f(|a|,|b|,|c|)$$

I need you to convince him  by a theorem or by reference in a book I don't know what to do

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function $$g:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R},\qquad t\mapsto g(t)$$  is even then for $t\geq0$ one has $g(t)=g\bigl(|t|\bigr)$, and for $t<0$ one has $g(t)=g(-t)=g\bigl(|t|\bigr)$. Therefore
$$g(t)=g\bigl(|t|\bigr)\qquad\forall t\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
When $f:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}$ is even in each variable then, according to this principle, for fixed $b$, $c$  the function
$$\phi(a):=f(a,b,c)$$
satisfies
$$\phi(a)=\phi\bigl(|a|\bigr)\qquad\forall a\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
It follows that for all $b$, $c$ we have
$$f(a,b,c)=f\bigl(|a|,b,c\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
Now, for fixed $a$, $c$ the left side of $(1)$ by assumption, and therefore also the right side of $(1)$,  are even functions of $b$. It follows that
$$f\bigl(|a|,b,c\bigr)=f\bigl(|a|,|b|,c\bigr)\qquad \forall b\in{\mathbb R}\ ,$$
and on and on. All this is a complicated way of saying that you were right in the first place.

Comment: Thanks sir so much for ur time hope that convinced him!

Comment: $U$ must be symmetrical with respect to $0$